What is the best way to write a serializer for enum and subsequent display in drf_spectacular?
I want to create a constructor for enum serializers to use them in views later and correctly display data in Swagger, especially in the schema.
My typical enum:
class EServicePlatform(models.IntegerChoices):
    ONLINE = 1, 'Online'
    OFFLINE = 2, 'Offline'


Which are directly sent to views as a dictionary:
django
Copy code
class DictionaryPlatforms(APIView):
    @extend_schema(responses={
        200: OpenApiResponse(response=DictionarySerializer(enum_class=EServicePlatform, many=True)),
        400: OpenApiResponse(description='Bad Request')}
    )
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = [{"value": item.value, "label": item.label} for item in EServicePlatform]
        serializer = DictionarySerializer(data=data, many=True, enum_class=EServicePlatform)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

The serializer constructor itself:
class DictionarySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[])  # Set an empty list by default
    label = serializers.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Expect enum_class to be passed via kwargs
        enum_class = kwargs.pop('enum_class', None)
        if not enum_class:
            raise ValueError("enum_class is required")

        # Dynamically set choices based on the passed enum class
        self.fields['value'].choices = enum_class.choices

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.enum_class = enum_class

    def validate(self, data):
        # Automatically add the label corresponding to the value
        data['label'] = dict(self.enum_class.choices)[data['value']]
        return data


In the current implementation, two problems arise:

It seems to me that the logic is overly complicated and it can be significantly simplified. But how?
For some reason, Swagger pulls data from a different enum, which is in another application entirely, and not from the one we are passing.

